# How can i get the parameter form label when parameter is variable in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I try to use following for-loop for testing.

```
@echo off

@for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a:d ') do (
    call :AAA
    echo def %def% 
    if "%def%" == "123" (echo yes) else (echo no)
)

:AAA
set "abc=123"
set "def=%abc%"
echo AAA %def%
```

run result:

```
AAA 123
def
no
AAA 123
def
no
AAA 123
def
no
AAA 123
def
no
AAA 123
```

I want to get def parameter form label's variable.
But it looks doesn't get the variable from label.

how to get parameter from label if the parameter is define variable?

Comment: What you've posted isn't worth answering because it has no use/purpose. If you were to tell us the genuine task then the motivation for responses would be more likely to increase.

Comment: i'm writing a script of batch file. those code is part of script. i cannot post complete on here. so i just for a simple example. Welcome to edit it If you think there has better description. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two simple bugs.
First you forget an `exit /b` after your for loop, this results in one extra execution of the `:AAA` block after the loop is finished.

The seconds problem is your percent expansion use inside a block can't work, as percent expansion occours when a block is parsed, before the code block is executed.
You need delayed expansion here.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a:d ') do (
    call :AAA
    echo def !def!
    if "!def!" == "123" (echo yes) else (echo no)
)
EXIT /B

:AAA
set "abc=123"
set "def=%abc%"
echo AAA %def%
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, it works. due to  those code is part of script. i cannot post complete on here. so i just for a simple example. thanks for remind about `exit /b`.